# Не запускаются python-сценарии после установки двух версий Python в Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Всем привет.
Была тихая январская ночь, когда понадобилось установить версию Python 3.7.2(x64)(на диск E:\) на рабочее место, где уже была версия Python 3.6.4(x86) (на диске C:\). 
Т. е. установка новой версии 3.7.2(x64) проводилась в другой диск и папку на ПК.

Использую:
ОС: Windows 7 Professional (x64)
Visual Studio Code - далее VSC - (на текущий момент последняя в этой вселенной версия: 1.30.2). 
Полные данные:

[image: Данные о версии VSC]

После установки VSC "подцепил" и новую версию 3.7.2(x64), в списке выбора интерпретаторов версия также появилась.
Через:
[путь_к_новой_версии]\pip.exe freeze -r [имя_файла_с_модулями] 
установил все модули, что были на 3.6.4(x86).

Всё работало некоторое время исправно, а потом началась какая-то феерическая вакханалия. При закрытии и запуске VSC стало появляется сообщение о необходимости выбрать интерпретатор и установить pylint:

[image: Сообщение о выборе интерпретатора и необходимости установить pylint]

Решил, что раз VSC не может правильно определить версию интерпретатора, то "должен остаться только один Python".
Удалил Python 3.6.4(x86), который был на диске C:\.
В настройках рабочей области явно указывается, какую версию интерпретатора использовать:

[image: Данные pythonPath]

И VSC теперь определяет единственную оставшуюся на ПК версию:

[image: Текущая и единственная версия Python]

Но появилась другая проблема: 
VSC теперь вообще не реагирует на запуск любых сценариев. Даже простой print('Bye forever, world!!!') не запускается. После запуска (первое нажатие F5) даже не определяются основные переменные, после второго нажатия F5 - ничего.

Суть в коротком видеоролике:
[VSC и Python не дружат...](https://yadi.sk/i/nRG9VGRtFgy3RQ)

Поиск на англоязычных форумах внятного ответа также не дал. Просьба указать направление, куда копать )
Заранее большое спасибо за поддержку!

Примечание:
Возможно, это поможет: на домашнем ПК установлена версия Python 3.7.2(x64), которая до вчерашнего вечера благополучно работала. Но потом точно также перестала запускать даже простейшие сценарии.

Важное примечание:
Выяснил, что режим запуска сценария в VSC "Начать без отладки" (Ctrl + F5) прекрасно работает. Таким образом, проблема именно в запуске сценариев с отладкой через F5.
Краткое видеодоказательство:
["Начать без отладки" - работает](https://yadi.sk/i/zt-raI4sDoYSUw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переустановка Visual Studio Code не помогла.

Проблема решена.
Всё заработало (вернулся вожделенный F5) и без переустановки - достаточно было сменить папку/диск Рабочей области (местонахождения папок и файлов с кодом Python).
Всем спасибо за участие и ментальную поддержку :)